# Scaling level of PWM signals

Tags: mosfet, servo, scaling

I am going to scale PWM 24V generated by PLC to PWM +5V by means of optocoupler TLP521 and MOSFET BSP295 in order to control a micro servo motor (MG90S).
What I have tried till now is the below circuit:

[image]

I have two questions please:
1. Will it work as I expect?
2. Are there any better circuits to tackle my problem (Converting PWM 24V to 5V)?

**Edit:** (based on comments)
1. Required frequency is 50 Hz.
2. Due to current limitation I am not able to use opto transistor directly.
3. The two sides are going to be isolated.

Comment: Why don't you simply just use two resistors?

Comment: Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: @Transistor I tried to save it but it was unsuccessful and I decided to upload its image.

Comment: @Andyaka, the two sides are going to be isolated. Sorry if schematic does not illuminate it.

Comment: You need to use the "Save and Insert" button. I think it has been a bit flakey today. I had trouble trying to save a schematic.

Comment: Why not connect Q1's collector directly to the GPIO and use an internal pull up? PWM frequency might be one reason due to opto response and capacitance. Add the expected frequency of operation into your question.

Comment: The frequency is 50 Hz being appropriate for opto. The current limitation, being 50 mA, is the reason.

Comment: Current limitation of what? It won't change anything on the LED side and a 1k pull-up on the Q1 side would limit current to 5 mA.

Comment: You are right. What about the drawback which is inverse on/off? When opto is ON if I use its collector directly the output will be OFF and vice versa.

Comment: The servo shouldn't draw any noticeable current on the PWM input.  It is a control signal, not a power input.  You should be able to drive it just fine from the optoisolator.

Comment: Are you certain your PLC is generating a PWM signal compatible with a hobby RC servo?  It's 50 Hz, but the pulse width ranges from 1 to 2 milliseconds only.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the circuit by using a Broadcom [ACPL-021L](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AV02-3462EN) logic-output optoisolator.

The input resistor must be increased, something like 7.5K would work. Just wire the output side to +5/GND and the servo input and add a bypass capacitor.

[image]

That particular part is non-inverting, like your circuit (input high = output high). If you can use inverting, then there are other more common options in logic-output optoisolators.

The input signal at the servo input should be a positive 3-5V pulse of width 1.0 to 2.0 milliseconds (1.5ms representing a position at about half travel), repeated at some tens of Hz frame rate (non-critical).

Answer (score 0):

A circuit that makes everything could be something like ISO [121x](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso1212.pdf)

Connecting **SENSE PIN** to the PWM 24V signal through the **Rt resistor** (used to set the threshold of the input level)

**IN PIN** connected to **SENSE** through a Rsense resistor to set the maximum current limit.

**FGND** the ground of 24V

**VCC1** 5V

**GND1** Ground of 5V

**OUT** 5V PWM isolated

the output current limit forces the use of a buffer like [MIC4126/27/28](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MIC4126-7-8.pdf)